# Zooming in a page breaks the layout in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: css, firefox

A web-page I've made works fine in Chrome and in Firefox when it isn't zoomed, however, the zoom breaks the layout in Firefox (but, for some reason, not in Chrome). You can see the [live version](https://flatassembler.github.io/analogClock.html).
Here is what it looks like in Firefox:
[image: Firefox when not zoomed in]
However, when zoomed in, it looks like this:
[image: Firefox when zoomed in]
Here is the CSS code of that web-page:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#format_as_code {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
  width: calc(80 * 7.2px);
  background: #111111;
  color: #eeeeee;
  height: calc(24 * 14.5px);
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: calc(80 * 7.2px);
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a 80x24 terminal (DOS-like) look in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63338625/how-to-get-a-80x24-terminal-dos-like-look-in-css)

Comment: @Gad No, that question has nothing to do with zooming.

Answer (score 1):

As long as i can tell even zooming-in in firefox doesn't break the layout (see the screenshot below). Maybe you may want to remove the width from the `<span id = "format_as_code">` or set it to auto to see if anything changes at all.
Quick tip for performances thought: i've noticed that every seconds all the spans (which i think represent the pixels of your canvas) updates, even the ones that don't change at all !
This leads to a noticeable performance decrease so may want to look into it.
I'll attach a screenshot of how i see the website and how it renders on FF 79 64bit.
Hope this helped you a little!

[image]

Comment: I am using Firefox 68. Thanks for the info that it's solved in the later versions.